# measure of dependence for copula

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

I have some question about the paper of Schweizer and Wolff (1981).
The question concerns about the following bound

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1|C(u,v)-uv|\,du\,dv\leq\frac{1}{12}$$ where $C$ is any copula.

I'm not quite sure whether it's exactly 1/12 since my attempt got 7/12.
Hence, my question is how can it be 1/12. Thanks in advanced for any response.

Comment: The integral in the paper seems to be correct. How did you get 7/12?

Comment: I use triangle inequality and $C(u,v)\le M(u,v)$ for all copula $C$ then

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}|C(u,v)-uv|du dv&\le\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}C(u,v)du dv+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}uvdu dv\\
&\le\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}M(u,v)du dv+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}uvdu dv\\
&=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\\
&=\frac{7}{12}.\\
\end{align*}

Could you tell me the way to prove $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}|C(u,v)-uv|du dv\le\frac{1}{12}$?

Answer (score 0):

Fact : $W\leq C\leq M$ for all copula $C$ where $M(u,v)=\min(u,v)$ and $W(u,v)=\max(u+v-1,0)$

Compute
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1|M(u,v)-W(u,v)|\,du\,dv=\int_0^1\int_0^1M(u,v)-W(u,v)\,du\,dv=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{6}=\frac{2}{12}.$$

Since $P(u,v)=uv$ is copula and $W< P< M$,
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1|C(u,v)-P(u,v)|\,du\,dv\leq\frac{2}{12}.$$

I think that $\int_0^1\int_0^1|C(u,v)-uv|\,du\,dv\leq\frac{1}{12}$ is correct but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, using the inequality $W\leq C\leq M$ for all copulas $C$ where $M(u,v)=\min(u,v)$ and $W(u,v)=\max(u+v-1,0)$, it is sufficient to compute the integrals that bound the sought after integral:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 (W(u,v)-uv)\,du\,dv \leq \int_0^1\int_0^1 (C(u,v)-uv) \,du\,dv \leq \int_0^1\int_0^1 (M(u,v)-uv) \,du\,dv$$

Those bounds do indeed evaluate to $-1/12$ for the lower one and $1/12$ for the upper one, therefore proving the inequality of OP.